# Swift - How to resize a UIView based on its UILabel size (that is inside)

Tags: swift, layout, uiview, uilabel

I'm a bit new in Swift, and I need some help with this:

I have a UILabel inside a UIView, and this label can receive any ammount of text. So I want to resize the UILabel based on the text it receives, and also resizes its container, the UIView. The UILabel must have a max width but not max height. It is very similar to what happens in Whatsapp with a message text (his green container grows accordly the text inside).

I believe it is about auto layout, but I really can't understand most of it.

EDIT: Create dynamically.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: UIView and Label are added using StoryBoard or adding Thorough code ? any tried Code ?

Comment: Label inherits from UIView, so there's that. Or jsut set UIView to the width of the label (you can do this in the storyboard).

Comment: Only by code, it is like a chat.

Answer (score 10):

The UIView that contains the Label should not have a fixed height then.
Just add constraints to set the UIView width and the X/Y coordinates.

Inside it the UILabel should have fixed constraints to Top/Bottom and Right/Left to the UIView and also set it's numberOfLines to 0

With these constraints the container View will expand to adjust the height based on the text.

See attached Screenshots

**Adding Container View Constraints (notice no bottom or height constraint added)**
[image: Adding Container View Constraints (notice no bottom or height constraint added)]

**Adding Label Constraints (fixed constraints to all UIView Edges)**

[image: Label Constraints (fixed constraints to all UIView Edges)]

**Result with short text**

[image: Result with short text]

**Result with long text**

[image: Result with long text]

Comment: And what if the view and label starts smaller (about 30px), and the view must grow his width too, until it have about 300px deppending the text of the label? I will create all this dinamically, but there is no problem if you explain using IB.

Comment: How would I do this programmatically since I have to pass a CGRect?? I have a view that is constraint left and right, but I need to pass height.

Answer (score 1):

In code, there are a couple scenarios when using a label inside a container view.

If the label is the only subview of the container you need only constrain it to the container's bounds, and set the label's `contentCompressionResistancePriority` and `contentHuggingPriority` both to `required`. If you do that there is no need to specify the height; the height will grow with the label.

```
class LabelContainerView: UIView {
    
    let label = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonSetup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonSetup()
    }
    
    func commonSetup() {
        addSubview(label)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        label.text = "Hello, World."
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
        
        ])
    }
    
}
```

If you want some padding around the label you can constrain it to the superview's `layoutMarginsGuide` and additionally adjust the `layoutMargins` to expand/shrink the padding.

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor),
    label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor),
    label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor),
    label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor)
])

// Uncomment for more padding
//layoutMargins = .init(top: 40, left: 40, bottom: 40, right: 40)
```

However, if you have an additional view inside the container (for example, a custom background view) you need to tell auto layout to use the label's `intrinsicContentSize`.

```
 @IBDesignable
 class ContainerView: UIView {
     
     let customBackgroundView = CustomBackgroundView()
     let label = UILabel()
     
     override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
         label.intrinsicContentSize // <-- Here
     }

     override init(frame: CGRect) {
         super.init(frame: frame)
         commonSetup()
     }
     
     required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
         super.init(coder: coder)
         commonSetup()
     }
     
     func commonSetup() {
         addSubview(customBackgroundView)
         addSubview(label)
         customBackgroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
         label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
         label.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
         label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
         label.text = "Hello, World."
         NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
             customBackgroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
             customBackgroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
             customBackgroundView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
             customBackgroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
             label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor),
             label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor),
             label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor),
             label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor)
         
         ])
     }
     
 }


class CustomBackgroundView: UIView {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonSetup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonSetup()
    }
    
    func commonSetup() {
        backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds)
        UIColor.red.setStroke()
        path.stroke()
    }
    
}
```

Many times, auto layout ambiguities can be resolved by using the `intrinsicContentSize`. This gives the necessary hint to the layout
engine how to calculate its internal views' size.

If a view has only an intrinsic height and not width (or vice versa) always use the constant `UIView.noIntrinsicMetric` for the undefined dimension.

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize { 
    .init(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: 42)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Lefteris' answer is correct. No need to define the width and height of the containing view. You just need to contraint it in its parent edges, then constraint the label inside it in the containing view's edges.

Here is how I did it in code.

```
let containingView: UIView = UIView()
containingView.translateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
addSubview(containingView)

let labelInside: UILabel = UILabel()
labelInside.translateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
containingView.addSubview(labelInside)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  //in my case, i want my containingView on the top left corner of the superView.
   containingView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
   containingView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),

   labelInside.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containingView.leadingAnchor),
   labelInside.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containingView.trailingAnchor),
   labelInside.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containingView.topAnchor),
   labelInside.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containingView.bottomAnchor)
])
```

Now if you want to have some margins / insets in your label, you can just add a constant when defining the constraints. :) HTH

Answer (score -2):

Below property works for me,hope this will helps

```
 [label sizeToFit];
```